# Reading a file and convert columns to rows in python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to convert numbers on the text files from columns to rows

From:

```
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
n
```

To like this: [1,2,3,4,5..n]

Comment: opencv? Are u sure?

Comment: Okay; so what is your *question*? Do you know how to read the file? What is your idea about how solving the problem will work, and what part of it don't you know how to do?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
with open(filename) as fh:
    print(fh.readlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` should work.


If you're using Linux:

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()

contents = contents.replace("\n", ", ")
print(contents)
```

Windows:

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()

contents = contents.replace("\r\n", ", ")
print(contents)
```

On macOS:

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()

contents = contents.replace("\r", ", ")
print(contents)
```